# SignalR Web Application receives messages from Console Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, console-application

I have setup a small project composed by a Console Application (*my messages Hub*) and a Web Application (*my messages receiver*).
The idea is that the Console Application listen to a RabbitMQ queue and every time a message is received, it broadcast the message to all SignalR Clients connected.

I initialize the Console App in this way:

```
// start Mass Transit Bus
var busControl = BuildBus();
busControl.Start();

// Start SignalR
string url = "http://localhost:9090";
using (WebApp.Start(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("SignalR Server running on {0}", url);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then I have my Startup class and my Hub Class as following:

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Now is where I get lost.

**Question 1**
I want from my Web Application to receive messages, so I initialize the proxy and then?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        //Set the hubs URL for the connection
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:9090/signalr";

            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            // Declare a Message handler

        });
</script>
```

**Question 2**
From the Console Application, how do I broadcast a message to all Clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1** You should define client methods as `chat.client.someMethod = function(someParams)`. In your case this client method is `chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {}`.

**Answer 2** If you want broadcast some message without connection to your hub from .NET application, then you can do this in this way: `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients.All.addMessage(/*method params*/)`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't find it inside the documentation, thanks